# NetBeans - C++ build current project

Tags: c++, netbeans

When you work on NetBeans there is a defined main project.
And when ever you press the build or run button that project is being executed.

I was wondering if there is a way to build the current project I'm viewing.
So say I jump between projects and hit the run button, the project it will run will be the one in my current edit view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the newest version of Netbeans, currently 7.2, there's no such things as main project. Hitting F11 or the icon will automatically build the project which file you're viewing.

Comment: unfortunately in 8.0 there is a main project and if you set it you can apparently only build other projects by right clicking the relevant project in the project files treeview.